# Image src from Javascript placed in same Java package

Tags: java, javascript, html, image

I have placed a .js file in a Java package along with a .css file and required image. The directory structure is:

- info.release.wicket.custom.ajax.link

  - AjaxLoadingLink.java
  - AjaxLoadingLink.css
  - AjaxLoadingLink.js
  - indicator.gif

Now from the .css file the indicator.gif can be accessed as `background-image:url(indicator.gif);`. But in the .js file `spinner.innerHTML = "<img src='indicator.gif'>";` is not working.

What will be the path of the image from the Javascript in this situation.

If I placed the image into resources folder of the WAR and access it as `spinner.innerHTML = "<img src='../resources/indicator.gif'>";` it is working. But I need to accomplish this by the aforesaid way, that is placing into the package.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: What does Java have to do with that?

Comment: Retagged this with html as well.

Answer (score 0):

The path to indicator.gif will be relative to the actual HTML document that the js file is called in. If the .gif is in the same folder as the html doc (or i guess .java file in your case?), then you can call it from there.

Comment: thanks. But in this scenario I have no need the call the image from .java file. The methods of .js are called from the .java and so the image should be accessed from that .js.

Comment: When you load that javascript in, any paths inside of it are going to be relative to whatever you loaded it into, so whether it's an HTML file or a .java file, your path has to be relative to that containing file. Javascript never actually runs by itself...its content is downloaded into the container environment and run inline. Calling out to it with an src is no different than writing it inline, so all of your path references are relative to the container environment.

Answer (score 0):

Why place the JS in a java package? If you put all the files in a directory e.g. /ajaxloading/ it should work. Java resources in packages are put in WEB-INF\classes you can't adress resources via relaitive url from there.

Another possibility is to write a servlet that serves all files form a package and then map this servlet to an url vial servlet-mapping in web.xml.

I also use this in a project. Here's the source:

```
public class StyleProviderServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7156462313946659366L;

    /**
     * read buffer.
     */
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 102400;

    private final org.slf4j.Logger logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(StyleProviderServlet.class);

    /**
     * Package
     */
    private static final String PACKAGE = "com/mycompany/mypackage/style";

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    this.handleRequest(req, resp);
    }

    protected void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    String pathInfo = req.getPathInfo();
    logger.debug("pathInfo = {}", pathInfo);

    StringBuilder resourcePathBuilder = new StringBuilder(100);
    resourcePathBuilder.append("/");
    resourcePathBuilder.append(PACKAGE);
    resourcePathBuilder.append(pathInfo);
    String resourcePath = resourcePathBuilder.toString();
    logger.debug("resourcePath: {}", resourcePath);

    InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(resourcePath);

    if (inputStream != null) {
        String mimeType = getMimeType(pathInfo);
        if (mimeType != null) {
        resp.setContentType(mimeType);
        }

        BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
        try {
        logger.debug("at least {} bytes are ready to be read", bufferedInputStream.available());
        ServletOutputStream outputStream = resp.getOutputStream();
        int index = -1;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        while ((index = bufferedInputStream.read(buffer)) != (-1)) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, index);
        }

        } finally {
        bufferedInputStream.close();
        }
    } else {
        logger.debug("no resource found for resourcePath '{}'", resourcePath);
    }
    }

    protected String getMimeType(String pathinfo) {
    if (pathinfo != null) {
        ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext();
        String mimeType = servletContext.getMimeType(pathinfo);
        logger.debug("pathInfo :{}, mimeType={}", pathinfo, mimeType);
        return mimeType;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    this.handleRequest(req, resp);
    }
}
```

And here's the mapping in web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>StyleProviderServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/style/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Now you can access all files from the package com/mycompany/mypackage/style via the url /style/ e.g. /style/AjaxLoadingLink.css

You can also put all files in a JAR this way and put this JAR into WEB-INF/lib